# Do SQL update statements always end in WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql

I'm developing a system such that users can input queries into the system and the system verifies the query. When the user enters an update statement, I wish to reuse that WHERE clause for an internal select statement.

For example, let's say the user enters:

```sql
UPDATE Customers
SET ContactName = 'Alfred Schmidt', City= 'Frankfurt'
WHERE CustomerID = 1;
```

I'd like to reuse `WHERE CustomerID = 1` (most likely by taking the substring) for a system select statement to verify that the recently updated rows are in a valid format:

System enters:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID = 1;
```

Is this safe? Do all SQL statements end in WHERE clauses?

Comment: No. You can have an Update statement without Where clause (affects all rows).

Comment: And an `INSERT` statement **must NOT** have a `WHERE` clause - so **NO**, not all SQL statement end in a `WHERE` clause....

Comment: And `Create Table`... is also considered to be an `SQL` statement, isn't it https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Comment: _"to verify that the recently updated rows are in a valid format"_ that is the wrong tool, you need to use constraints for that.

Comment: Yet another https://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Comment: There are red flags waving all over this design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out the official docs for your specific flavor of SQL, as implementations vary. For instance,

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) allows for ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses after UPDATE...WHERE.
- [Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has an optional OPTION clause that can follow WHERE.
- [Oracle's SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html) looks like WHERE is safely the last part of an UPDATE (at least for the version linked here).
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-update.html) allows for a RETURNING clause.
- etc.

Of course, the WHERE clause could be omitted in any, though it's not usually what you'd want to do.

Comment: Good point. Mine is SQLite which seems to only end in WHERE clauses for UPDATE statements: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 0):

No.

A SQL statement like

```
UPDATE Customers 
SET ContactName = 'Alfred Schmidt';
```

will simply update all entries in the table without any restriction on which rows to update in a where clause.

Comment: That's fair! I guess I can check for whether WHERE exists in the statement itself.

Comment: Update statements with no `WHERE` clause usually indicate a smell.

Answer (score 0):

> Do all SQL statements end in WHERE clauses?

Good question.

As a definition attempt "what is an SQL statement anyway?": If you mean the common SQL and not so much all the DBMS-specific flavors, then I'd say the most popular daily-used standard `SQL` statements would perhaps be only a few, `Select`, `Update`, `Delete`, that can have a `Where` clause, and `Insert` that cannot. And `Merge` AKA `Upsert` that has a `When`. And I think many people would postulate that those three that *can have a `Where`, normally also *do or even *should have one, at least in a scalable `industrial` context.

Answer (score -1):

SQL update statements are valid with a `Table` and `column = value`. However, it is usually considered bad form to leave off any filter. Also, `where` isn't the only filter possible there's also `having` or the `on` portion of a join.

Comment: ...and the `On` conditions of `Inner` or `Outer` `Join`s

Comment: good catch, updated